# Generating a file path

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Does anyone know a tool for showing the path from one file to another?  Ie, if my css file is in:

```
/User/foo/bar/source/assets/myscreen
```

and my image is in:

```
/User/foo/bar/gamethings/smallimages
```

How can I quickly, without having to count the file levels (which is simple, but tedious, and has to be done often), generate the path from the css to the image?

Comment: A task that is simple, but tedious, and has to be done often. If only there were some kind of *machine* that could perform such labors for us...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, get `realpath(1)` from GNU Coreutils. Then:

```
$ realpath --relative-to=/User/foo/bar/source/assets/myscreen /User/foo/bar/gamethings/smallimages
../../../gamethings/smallimages
```